# I got this error "Tuple has no attribute 'obj'"

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error and I don't understand why:

```
Tuple has no attribute 'obj'
```

Here is my code:

```
def upload_list(request):
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    cn = pdf.values_list('client').distinct()
    print(cn)
    for i in range(len(cn)):    
        client = Client_Process.objects.filter(client__in=cn[i])
        cn[i].obj = client
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example next time. Looking at the snippet, it must be to do with the line cn[i].obj = client as that's where the obj attribute is being accessed. Most likely, cn[i] is actually a tuple of objects while you expect a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

`cn = pdf.values_list('client').distinct()`

to:

`cn = pdf.distinct()`

".values_list()" returns a list of tuple instead of a list of Model instances i.e QuerySet.